# Embed app built with ember-cli (where to specify rootElement?)

Tags: ember-cli

I need to embed an ember app made with ember-cli into an existing website.

Without ember-cli i would do this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app-container'
});
```

I am basically looking to include the generated assets into my page and not use the index.html file at all.. (The app needs to bind to a div not the body element..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow. Cant believe I didn't try this already..

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: 'kontrollpanel', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver,
  rootElement: '#myapp'
});
```

I guess i was confused with the use of Application.extend() instead of the Application.create().
As to why ember-cli uses extend i found an answer here: [SO: Why ember cli uses extend instead of create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914677/why-ember-cli-uses-extend-instead-of-create)

Comment: where did you put the /dist folder and how did you do the reference to the app? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Just copy the css and js from dict/assets to wherever you want to place them, and reference them like you would with any other asset.